# triangle background with css

Tags: css, background

I want to create a `div` with background like this:

[image]

But I also want to scale it with width 100% and height about 500px. I used some gradient generators but I have to specify degree and I cant scale it. Can I make this using only css?

I want get the line in this background exactly from one corner to another.

Is the only option scale height too? with for example 50% and specify exact degree value in gradient attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A linear gradient can be defined without angles and use positions instead

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/bgg2r/)

**Gradient defaults from top left**

```
linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, red 50%, blue 50% , blue);
```

Comment: Is this cross-browser? I've tried:
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right bottom, rgb(42, 105, 163) 0%, rgb(45, 114, 163) 51%, rgb(77, 255, 157) 100%, rgb(72, 149, 196) 100%);
...
But the line is not exactly from one corner to another. That's why i ask

Comment: Should be but I note you are missing the 'to' statement. Opera Mini does not allow gradients though.